# How to Compile fla and as into a swf

Tags: actionscript-3, compilation, flash, fla

Ok first of thanks for reading..

first off to tell you what im doing. im editing the action script of an swf file
ok i decompiled it got a folder containing the as  and the fla-flash part of the swf
now i edited what i needed to in the few as files.

now the question is the fla no longer has all the as that was in the swf it is in the folder along with the orignal fla that was made

how do i go ahead and compile all the as and fla together to publish the swf again

again note if i try to publish the fla it is half the size (the as part isnt in there)

is there a way i can do this easily.?
thanks again

any helpful comments greatly appreciated thanks again

Comment: Compile FLA to SWF ? It's the default function of Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 0):

> again note if i try to publish the fla it is half the size (the as
>   part isnt in there)

This shouldn't happen because of .as files not being compiled. It should be because you must be missing some other symbols and their linkages in your fla.

I hope you are using some tool like Adobe Professional CS5 etc for editing and seeing the fla

1. Check whether the ActionScript Settings has the correct folder for the sources file
2. In your main document of the fla, check whether the Document class is set. You can also click on the pen mark beside the document to open it up.
3. check your library containing all the symbols and their linkages

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a problem with your decompiler. First off, you shouldn't be using one since the majority of them out there are far from perfect. You didn't exactly give enough details other than the fact that you want to get your decompiler to work, so I don't see what the issue is.